# escape single quotes inside javascript function - output variable in google analytics tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to pull a variable into a parameter to fire a Google Analytics event. The paramater must be enclosed in single quotes for the event to be recorded properly in GA.

What I have below just sends `droppedObject` as the value in Google Analytics instead of the actual value of the variable. I have read through many suggestions on SO about escaping quotes but all produce an "unexpected identifier" error message and my draggable/droppable widget breaks.  Note: I do not get any error messages with the code below, but it doesn't output what I want.

```
var droppedObject = ui.draggable.data('object');
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Perfect Pair', 'Dropped', 'droppedObject' ]);
```

Here is an example of the HTML where the object data is defined.

```
        <li class="draggable" data-object="soleil">
        <img src="../assets/pairs/soleil_lid.png" height="40">
        <p class="soleil">Soleil</p>
        </li>
```

In this case, the desired output would be soleil

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Perfect Pair', 'Dropped', 'soleil' ]);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does this have to do with regexes?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sorry, i am new to all of this - the only time i've ever had to escape special characters was when writing regex for google analytics so i assumed this was part of it. i have removed that tag from my question.

Comment: "unexpected identifier" (in Chrome) is a syntax error. However, the code above has no syntax errors assuming it's directly in a script file or HTML script tag. Can you post the overall context that this code appears in? (note: although syntax is fine, it is tracking a meaningless string rather than the value you want...).

Comment: @FabioBeltramini I don't get the error with the code above, but I get it when I try to do add backslashes or anything I read in other posts about escaping single quotes. I just need to know the right way to insert backslashes in here so I can use the single quotes around the variable value.

Comment: And in your console when you write droppedObject, is the result you see a string? (in Chrome, it will be in red text encolosed by double quotes)

Comment: You don't need to escape the quotes..

Comment: Ok, then how do I achieve the desired output? If I leave it like this: _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Perfect Pair', 'Dropped', 'droppedObject' ]);  it sends droppedObject to google analytics as a string, rather than soleil, or whatever value droppedObject actually is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46031/discussion-between-surfbird0713-and-fabio-beltramini)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a string, rather than your variable:

Try:

```
var droppedObject = ui.draggable.data('object');
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Perfect Pair', 'Dropped', droppedObject ]);
```

Comment: the variable has to be contained within single quotes for it to work properly with google analytics

Comment: Right, and it will be in single quotes. What the variable is returning is a string. For example, ui.draggable.data('object') is returning the string inside of data-object='blah', so var droppedObject = 'blah', which is wrapped in single quotes. Try it once.

Comment: Oh I see... you want droppedObject.someProperty (where someProperty refers to a string with the name of the object. Just look at the object in your dev console to find the relevant property)

Comment: @Blexy I get the following error message when I try that: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: I just updated my question with more details too, hopefully taht will help.

Comment: I tried this again and it worked...not sure what happened the first time but thank you.